# Consensus symbols in multiple sequence alignment

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I was using [multAlin](http://multalin.toulouse.inra.fr/multalin/) for multiple aligning a set of sequences. The output I and came across included the following documentation (English corrected):

> Consensus symbols:
>   ! is any of IV
>   $ is any of LM
>   % is any of FY
>   # is any of NDQEBZ

I understand what it says but I don't know how to interpret it further. What impact does this have on the sequence alignment?

Comment: I find your post incomprehensible and am voting to close. However if you are having a problem with a software program I suggest you consult the documentation, the website or the support community.

Comment: Hi, this is the description:
 ! is anyone of IV
 $ is anyone of LM 
% is anyone of FY 
# is anyone of NDQEBZ
I have emailed them for help, and even follow up on that email, but i did not get a reply at all. I really hope some bioinformatics expert can help me here. Thank you

Comment: I have edited your question in a readable manner, which I would recommend if you post here again — the clearer you explain your problem, the more likely you are to get an answer. I have also answered your question, including sample output, that you would have done well to include in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The use of these symbols in output of the type shown below is purely presentational, to help you inspect the alignment and identify regions of partial conservation.

> ```
>                   51                                                 100
>           CCPC50  SEEGFK.YGE GILEVAEKNP DLTWTEADLI EYVTDPKPWL VKMTDDKGAK
>           CCRF2C  TYPEFK.YKD SIVALGASG. .FAWTEEDIA TYVKDPGAFL KEKLDDKKAK
>           CCRF2S  TQADFKGYGE GMKEAGAKG. .LAWDEEHFV QYVQDPTKFL KEYTGDAKAK
>           CCQF2R  HKDNYA.YSE SYTEMKAKG. .LTWTEANLA AYVKNPKAFV LEKSGDPKAK
>           CCQF2P  TFAGYS.YSP GYTVMGQKG. .HTWDDNALK AYLLDPKGYV QAKSGDPKAN
>        Consensus  t...%k.Y.e g..e.gakg. .ltWt#..l. .Yv.#Pk.fl .ek.gD.kAk
> ```
>
> [image: Multiple alginment]

This is quite independent of the logic (algorithm) of the program, which is indicated by the documentational comments:

> Symbol comparison table: blosum62
>   Gap weight: 12
>   Gap length weight: 2

This also gives a reference to the [original paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC338945/) you should read to find more information about the program.

You would also be advised to read the [Wikipedia entry on Multiple Sequence Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment) and on [Sequence Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) in general. I would mention that this is an old method (as the appearance of the site also indicates). If it gives useful results, fine. Otherwise you might try the more popular and more frequently updated Clustal, which is available [online](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalo/) or as a [standalone program](http://www.clustal.org).